# MySQL Replace Value From Each Record

Tags: php, mysql, replace, unique

I have a table in my database that looks like this:

=========
| id | code |
 =========
| 1  | a    |
 =========
| 2 | e     |
 =========
| 3 | r     |
 =========

and so on.  I would like to be able to do a query that will tell me which letters in the alphabet are **not** in the table.

I was originally thinking of a query like this:

SELECT REPLACE('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', (SELECT code FROM table), '');

and hoping that would output 'defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', and I could just explode that into an array of unused characters.  Unfortunately, MySQL's REPLACE doesn't allow a table of values to be used.

Any suggestions on how to build this list?

Comment: My MySql is a bit rusty, but it's a nice question. I think I'd be starting by looking at combining something with `WHERE NOT IN (SELECT code FROM table)`

Comment: @DerekTomes That's what I originally thought.  Unfortunately, it would require a separate static table of the entire alphabet for the "FROM" table.  I try to create an immediate table ('a', 'b', 'c'...), but that syntax isn't allowed in the FROM field

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Uhh, why do I need what?

Comment: What about creating another table with a-z as rows and doing an intersect/minus?

Comment: That silly a-z stuff. What is the real life problem you are trying to solve such unusual way?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Seems short-sighted.  Our accounting system uses single-character codes to represent types of hours (regular time, overtime, PTO, leave, etc.).  Naturally, it's bad UX to let the user try to create codes that overlap eachother.

Comment: So, you are trying to determine yet unused characters. Let me suggest you to normalize your database.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel From wikipedia: "Database normalization is the process of organizing the fields and tables of a relational database to minimize redundancy and dependency".  Where is the extraneous redundancy or dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would ***recommend*** to do it is to create a table with a row for each letter in the alphabet, that would make it easy to remove the letters with a LEFT JOIN and GROUP_CONCAT at the end.

Lacking that table, you'll have to resort to a hack, building a temporary "alphabet table" using a JOIN between a temporary variable and a table with more rows than the number of letters. For this example, I use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CHAR(ch) SEPARATOR '') 'missing letters' FROM 
  (SELECT @tmp:=@tmp+1 ch 
   FROM (SELECT @tmp:=96) a, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS
   WHERE @tmp<122) z
LEFT JOIN TableA ON ch=ORD(TableA.code)
WHERE TableA.code IS NULL;
```

The nested SELECT builds the alphabet sequence, the LEFT JOIN removes the letters that exist in TableA (your table). GROUP_JOIN concatenates the resulting letters. The result is a string with all letters that don't exist in TableA.

Answer (score 0):

Build the logic on the server side. Create a query to get all the used letters (distinct), then walk through the result set and clear out the used chars from the possible array/string.

Comment: Possible answer, and probably what I'm going to have to do.  Ideal situation would be to just do it from a SQL query, but this might have to suffice.

Comment: You can do it in sql: create a stored procedure which fill create a temp table whit all the possible letters then you only have to build a simple query to get the result.